# не работает функция click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var kek = '.content2';
var lol = '[name = ALL]';
$('[name = LOL]').click(function(){
    $(lol).css('color', 'black').css('background-color','white');   
    $('[name = LOL]').css('color', 'white').css('background-color','#ff8041');
    $('.content2').css('display','none');
    $('.content1').css('display','inline-block');
    lol = '[name = LOL]';
});

$('[name = KEK]').click(function(){
    alert("kek");   
    $(lol).css('color', 'black').css('background-color','white');
    $('[name = KEK]').css('color', 'white').css('background-color','#ff8041');
    $('.content1').css('display','none');
    $('.content2').css('display','inline-block');
    lol = '[name = KEK]';
});


$('[name = ALL]').click(function(){
    $(lol).css('color', 'black').css('background-color','white');
    $('[name = ALL]').css('color', 'white').css('background-color','#ff8041');
    $('.content1').css('display','inline-block');
    $('.content2').css('display','inline-block');
    lol = '[name = ALL]';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">
  <li><a class="butt" name="ALL" href="#">ALL</a></li>
  <li><a class="butt" name="LOL" href="#">LOL</a></li>
  <li><a class="butt" name="KEK" href="#">KEK</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="content1">
      <img class="img-circle col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" src="kek/big_1442858601_image.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="img-circle col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" src="kek/chto-takoe-kek.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="img-circle col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" src="kek/149323920613487653.png" alt="">
      <img class="img-circle col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" src="kek/1443982198_586740750.png" alt="">
      <img class="img-circle col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" src="kek/vaqwznmsb9e.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="content2">
      <img class="img-circle col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" src="memes/4a4c2a53661ede617bd7437b4e728cbb.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="img-circle col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" src="memes/9232.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="img-circle col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" src="memes/p5fhjd9nzmaurge1vlwb.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="img-circle col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" src="memes/09618544.jpg" alt="">
      <img class="img-circle col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" src="memes/1490197791_2.png" alt="">
      <img class="img-circle col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" src="memes/images.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот в этой строчке `$('[name = LOL]').click(function(){)` зачем тут в конце закрывающая круглая скобка?

Comment: это так помарка, прост дописывал и не заметил

Comment: `$('[data-name="LOL"]').click(function(){ ... });`

Comment: Igor, data-name - это я думал с ним сработает и забыл убрать, но увы так тоже не работает

Comment: а я вот поклацал, и работает :)

Comment: @МихаилНазаревич объясните, что не работает

Comment: Igor, должно по нажатию по ссылкам происходить скрытие блока, но ничего не происходит, даже если туда алерт впихнуть, то по нажатию он не вылезает. Прикол в том что тоже самый код работал в прошлом проекте, а сейчас нет (что безумно бесит)

Comment: @МихаилНазаревич "Спокойствие, только спокойствие." Под фрагментом кода в вопросе - кнопка "Выполнить код". Нажмите на нее и попробуйте пощелкать по ссылкам. Работает? Пожалуйста.

Comment: @Igor, Работает, а вот почему у меня не работает в html js файлах вот это не понятно

Comment: @МихаилНазаревич Напротив, понятно. У Вас не загрузился в страницу файл с jQuery - jquery-3.2.1.min.js. Откройте "Инструменты разработчика" в браузере (F12) и посмотрите ошибки в консоли.

Comment: @Igor, тогда бы были ошибки в консоли, а их нет. Я пробовал как локально, так и через CDN, но чот результат один и тот же

Comment: @МихаилНазаревич Хорошо. Значит у Вас в странице js код выполняется до того, как создадутся DOM-элементы, на которые Вы хотите навесить обработчики событий. Заверните код в `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`.

Comment: @Igor, аааа пасиба большое, дай бох здоровья, заработало)))

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать кавычки они у вас пропущены и не использовать пробелов между равно, тогда у вас все будет работать и не нужно обращаться к `.click()` - это функция которая вызывает клик, а не создает событие, т.е. когда вы что-то хотите чтобы нажалось используется `.click()`.

```
$('[name="LOL"]').on('click', function(){});
```

так же в функции `.css()` можно использовать объекты

```
$('[name="ALL"]').css({'color': 'white', 'background-color': '#ff8041');
```

Надеюсь что вам это поможет.

Comment: не работало так, когда кавычки добавлял

Comment: А почему вы не хотите обращаться по class`у или id элемента?

Comment: я и по ним обращался, тут проблема была в том что script надо было вызывать в футере, или .ready

Comment: если уж на то пошло, то .on('ready'), а вообще, да, скрипты лучше вешать перед закрывающимся тегом </body> т.к. у вас с начала загрузить скрипт который все начнет навешивать на себя, т.е. сканить DOM, который еще не до конца, а то и вовсе не загрузился.

Answer (score -2):

```
$('[data-name="LOL"]').click(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Поясняю для Катерины. Технический минус один ответу был дан учёткой Дух сообщества за редактирование ответа другим участником.

Comment: @AK ничего, минус - заслуженный. Она просто скопировала мой комментарий.

Comment: @AK, можно подробнее?

Comment: @AK, почему так, я ведь просто изменил форматирование?

Comment: @diraria, https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/689/207618

Comment: @Aid, спасибо, но я изменял ответ не из очереди проверок, а напрямую со страницы вопроса, кажется это отличается от случая описанного в том вопросе

Comment: @diraria, Вашу правку должны утвердить более опытные участники, которые, очевидно, и утвердили правку из очереди.

Comment: @Aid, спасибо !